# If a video on YouTube has been reported and got remove unfairly, how can the video owner contact YouTube on this issue?

Tags: youtube

If a video gets reported and removed, even though that video is not inappropriate, what is the best way to contact YouTube on the issue? I saw [this page](http://support.google.com/youtube/?hl=en_US&usrctx=IP_HP_HELP_CENTER_CLICKED) but I have not seen a way to contact them on this issue.

Comment: I just found this on a Google forum: When you get that warning there is an option to have YouTube re-review it. The option is still there to do that. Click on your name then Settings → Manage Account, then go to where you have the warning.

Comment: @Alex the person who got this issue can't do this account for 2 weeks, someone has bullied him by report his video repeatedly.

Comment: Check [this](http://youtube-global.blogspot.it/2010/07/strike-youre-out-or-maybe-not.html) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather old article, but might help you nevertheless.

> In the meantime, if you have content on YouTube that mysteriously vanishes, Google sent me a list of steps, which I've amended here, that you can follow to send a query to the right place:
>
> 1. Go to the Safety Center (link at the bottom of every page).
> 2. Click on the radio button "Community Guidelines Violations."
> 3. Click on Account Suspensions (right-hand corner). You will get a message that says "Read about inappropriate content"
> 4. Click on Contact Us, then Video Removal, then Video Removal Inquiry, then Learn more about video removals. From there the steps are clear.

[Source](http://www.cnet.com/8301-31361_1-10464091-254.html).